# I can't access a controller property in my angular2 view

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a interface

```
export interface IInterview {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
}
```

and when I do `console.log(interview)` in my controller it shows that I have

```
Object {title: "I SEE SOMETHING", id: 2, body: "THIS IS SO AWESOME HUEHUEHUEHUE"}
```

But when I go to my views and I do `{{ interview.body }}` I get an error saying

> Cannot read property 'body' of undefined in [
>       {{ interview.body }}

And when I try `{{ interview }}` it just says `[object Object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
{{ interview?.body }}
```

Reason:

The `interview` property of your component is probably `undefined` at the first moment angular tries to render the view.

The <s>elvis</s> **safe navigation operator** (`?.`) ensures that angular will only attempt to render the variable if it is not null.

If works roughly like `{{ interview ? interview.body : "" }}`.

You can find out more about it at the official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator or at the [cheatsheet](https://angular.io/cheatsheet).

Comment: I added an explanation, tell me what you think.

Comment: thanks, for including the name too... I was trying to google "question mark angularjs" haha. Accepting answer when I can :)

Comment: Hehe, now that you mentioned it, I think they renamed it from elvis to "safe navigation operator": https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/1139 -- "elvis operator" is the name it is usually known by in other languages that have it.

Comment: one more question if you don't mind... I have another function that does something very similar except it returns a list of json and I use an *ngFor to render it. How come I didn't have to use the safe navigation operator then?

Comment: I added a link to the official docs, just in case you wanted to check the it out.

Comment: About the second question, the `*ngFor` won't try to render if the collection is empty or undefined - it will silently ignore it, just like `interview?.`.